# Discord Bot Running Slow with Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, setinterval

I have a working countdown timer command with my discord bot and it works fairly well at the moment. The biggest issue that I am running into at this time is - if the command is executed again while there is already another instance running, it is extremely slow and will start to freeze up the command within discord.

I am expecting to be able to run this command more than once without any issue or lag. I am not sure what I can implement to make this command run faster when there is more than one instance of it running simultaneously.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits } = require("discord.js");
const moment = require("moment");
let eventMonth;
let eventDay;
let eventYear;
let time;

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("test-timer")
        .setDescription("Timer testing command")
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.ViewAuditLog)
        .addIntegerOption((option) => option
            .setName("event-month")
            .setDescription("month of the event")
            .setRequired(true)
        )
        .addIntegerOption((option) => option
            .setName("event-day")
            .setDescription("day of the event")
            .setRequired(true)
        )
        .addIntegerOption((option) => option
            .setName("event-year")
            .setDescription("year of the event")
            .setRequired(true)
        )
        .addStringOption((option) => option
            .setName("event-time")
            .setDescription("time of the event")
            .setRequired(true)
        ),

    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const message = await interaction.reply({
            content: `Days: 0 Hours: 0 - Mintues: 0 - Seconds: 0`,
            fetchReply: true
        });

        eventMonth = interaction.options.getInteger("event-month").toString();
        eventDay = interaction.options.getInteger("event-day").toString();
        eventYear = interaction.options.getInteger("event-year").toString();
        time = interaction.options.getString("event-time");

        const convertTime12to24 = (time12h) => {
            const [time, modifier] = time12h.split(' ');
            let [hours, minutes] = time.split(':');
            if (hours === '12') {
                hours = '00';
            }
            if (modifier === 'PM') {
                hours = parseInt(hours, 10) + 12;
            }
            return `${hours}:${minutes}`;
        }

        const timeFormat = `${convertTime12to24(time)}:00`

        let interval;
        const eventDayMoment = moment(`${eventYear}-${eventMonth}-${eventDay} ${timeFormat}`);

        const second = 1000;
        const minute = second * 60;
        const hour = minute * 60;
        const day = hour * 24;

        const countDownFn = () => {
            const today = moment();
            const timeSpan = eventDayMoment.diff(today);

            if (timeSpan <= -today) {
                console.log("Past the event day");
                clearInterval(interval);
                return;
            } else if (timeSpan <= 0) {
                console.log("Today is the day of the event");
                clearInterval(interval);
                return;
            } else {
                const days = Math.floor(timeSpan / day);
                const hours = Math.floor((timeSpan % day) / hour);
                const minutes = Math.floor((timeSpan % hour) / minute);
                const seconds = Math.floor((timeSpan % minute) / second);

                message.edit({
                    content: `Days: ${days} Hours: ${hours} - Mintues: ${minutes} - Seconds: ${seconds}`
                })
            }
        };
        interval = setInterval(countDownFn, second);
    }
};
```

Comment: Editing a message every second spams the Discord API, you will begin to encounter bottlenecking. The larger the interval, the better the function will run. Regardless, you can get banned from the API if you continue to  do this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into reconfiguring the countdown function then.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of editing your message repeatedly you could use Unix timestamps (in seconds). [[Docs]](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting)

Example:
`<t:1672300000:R>` => `17 hours ago`
`<t:1672400000:R>` => `in 11 hours`

As a side effect of using the format the formatted and translated according to the user's preferences,
it shows the exact time and date when hovering over the timestamp
and automatically updates without spamming the discord api.

Answer (score 0):

Most APIs these days have [ratelimits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting) to keep people from spamming them and degrading service quality for everyone else. When you try to make requests after hitting the rate limit, your requests are blocked and you get a **HTTP 429 Too Many Requests** status code.

#### How Discord's Rate Limits work

Discord, specifically, has a global ratelimit of 50 requests per second for every bot. Some bots outgrow that limit, [and have to contact their staff to get it increased](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#global-rate-limit).

On top of that, they also have per-resource rate limits, which are probaby the ones you're hitting here. This means that resources in different guilds or channels have different rate limits (and you'll probably be able to notice that your countdown timer doesn't slow down then ran in two different guilds at the same time).

#### And how Discord.js handles it

To help out a bit with this Rate Limiting madness, discord.js has a set of features that queue up your requests locally and only sends them to the Discord API whenever the Ratelimit allows it. **This is why your countdown timer is slow when you have too many instances of it running simultaneously.**